# Closures: assigning a field to a local captures which value?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures

I have the following pattern in a class:

```
Foo m_currentFoo;

void ReplaceFooWithDelayedDestruction() {
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        var oldFoo = m_currentFoo;
        Destroy(oldFoo);
    }
    m_currentFoo = new Foo();
}
```

My question is, when the lambda is executed (presumably after ReplaceFoo... has returned), will oldFoo actually refer to the value that was passed in on BeginInvoke, or to the new value of m_currentFoo?

Comment: You're actually capturing `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly capture the current foo before it gets overwritten, you should use a local variable in your enclosing function, otherwise you are running the risk of having your old foo hanging around and instead destroying your newly created foo instead.

```
Foo m_currentFoo;

void ReplaceFooWithDelayedDestruction()
{
    var oldFoo = m_currentFoo;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Destroy(oldFoo); } );

    m_currentFoo = new Foo();
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's right, I was confused about where the local had to go. This makes total sense.